# Relative Image Urls in Posts are starting from root - Not from WordPress Address (URL) at General Settings

Tags: posts, images, subdomains

The title pretty much explains all. But I wanted to ask that shouldn't it behave like this that relative image urls in posts should be started from wordpress address (url)?

I have a wordpress installed at:-

```
abc.com/wordpress/
```

But relative images in posts like this:-

```
<img src="/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/...png">
```

goes 404 with address:-

```
abc.com/wp-content/themes/....
```

And relative images in posts like this:-

```
<img src="wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/...png"> (without backslash at start)
```

goes 404 with address:-

```
abc.com/wordpress.com/post-slug/wp-content/themes/....
```

While in general settings the WordPress Address is:-

```
abc.com/wordpress
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this instead:

```
<img src="<?php echo site_url();?>"/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/...png">
```

You've installed your wordpress in a abc.com/wordpress folder.
So when you use the backslash you are refering to the root of your domain, instead of the folder were you've installed your WP.

Hope that is helps.
Cheers

Comment: php doesn't executes in post content. And I really don't want to enable it.